# Supporting 3D secure cards for recurring

Tags: java, paypal, credit-card, 2checkout, 3d-secure

My target is to support 3D secured cards for recurring billing. Right now I have implemented Paypal Direct payment. As Paypal Direct Payment API does not support 3D secure for recurring billing ;

> 3-D Secure is not supported for direct Recurring Billing and Reference
>   Transactions. Cards that require 3-D Secure authentication cannot use
>   these APIs

[3D secure implementation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/ThreeDSecure/#id096MB09805Z)

So I did some research and came across **2Checkout** which supports 3D secure. [here](http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/What-is-3-D-Secure/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle)

2Checkout also supports [Recurring billing](https://www.2checkout.com/faq#does-2checkout-support-recurring-billing).
First thing I want to know as it is not clearly written, does 2CO supports 3d secure for recurring as well?

Secondly is there any other way or source through which I can achieve my target more easily than 2CO.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

3D secure is only available on the first and initial transaction, which is also the reason for the expression `chargeback` and e.g. `friendly chargeback` which usually are only done on the recurring transaction and not on the initial one, since it have been approved by 3D secure and is pretty hard to disprove it's authenticity.